# О назначении препаратов

Tags: словосочетания

Оба варианта выражений возможны?

А) Выписать лекарства;
Б) Прописать лекарства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Выписать** в медицинском контексте воспринимается как выдача *письменного* документа на лекарства (рецепта или простой записки, если рецепт не требуется).

**Прописать** - то же, что **назначить** лекарство, сообщив об этом пациенту и записав напр. в историю болезни, - не обязательно с выпиской рецепта.